# ASP.Net Core JS works in _Layout, but not in body page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm quite new to ASP MVC, so maybe I'm making a newbie mistake here.

For my site, I wanted a standardized header and sidebar across all pages, so I put that in _Layout.cshtml and that works just fine. The main index page for my application (I will be adapting it later, but as I've just started, it's pretty much just identically this, if that's relevant: https://www.wrappixel.com/demos/free-admin-templates/matrix-admin/) contains a number of graphs and charts that I'd maybe like to eventually use, so I'm trying to make sure it stays functional as I set this up.

Now, if I were to call a set of JS files, and then call an initialization JS file from the _Layout.cshtml, all the charts load without issue. However, I figure that is bad practice, as I won't have all of these charts on every page. So I copied and pasted the imports for those JS files into my content page, but that strangely causes the charts to fail to load in. While I can ensure in the console that each of those JS files above did load in, via the debugger and networking tabs, my initialization script will fail, due to not finding a function in one of those above mentioned files.

My only two ideas are that there is an issue with the way I'm loading the page content, or that there's something up with resources 404'ing before being found. I believe this is all the code used for calling the content page:

```
<div>
    <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>
```

The other possibility I mentioned is strange 404's. Whenever I refresh a page, the console always gives me a few of these:

```
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://localhost:5001/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.js.map[Learn More]
```

These always resolve, as I can definitely find bootstrap as a loaded resource, but I'm wondering if the scripts being in the _Layout file just gives them more time to resolve, and by putting them in the actual content file, they just timeout before any resolution can be made?

I can't seem to find any sources that mention the differences where you put JS, other than the idea of not putting specialized resources into the _Layout file, obviously.

### Edit

I began to notice some other items also weren't working, so I got frustrated and removed all JS imports from the _Layout.cshmtl file, and that seemed to fix all issues. I suppose it's not possible to split up the importing of JS files like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understood, you handle "page-specific" resources (JS, CSS) using `sections` - `@RenderSection(...`.

While [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is for `Core`, instead of `MVC`, it doesn't matter because the concept is identical.

- They are "placeholders" you can set in your `Layout`
- You can "inject" something into them from a "Content Page"
- You position these "placeholders" appropriately (in `<head>`, `<body>`, or where scripts typically go - right before the closing `<body>` tag.

Taken from the linked document above, an example `Layout`:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link_to_bootstrap">
     @RenderSection("PageStyles", required: false)
     ....
   </head>
   <body class="theme">
        <div id="main-body">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <script src="path_to_jquery_or_cdn"></script>

        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

    </body>
```

In this example you can "inject" page-specific `PageStyles` and/or `Scripts` as needed.

Note the positioning of the "placeholder" - in this example the `Scripts` placeholder is positioned *after* the call to `jQuery` library. This ensures that some other js library dependent on jQuery will have it loaded. Same for the `PageStyles` "placeholder" - positioned after a css library (e.g. Bootstrap).

I suspect this is likely why your *" charts to fail to load in"* - re: loading order of inter-dependent scripts.

Example in some "content" page:

```
// because this page has a <form> that needs client side validation
// jquery validation is dependent on jquery library which we've already loaded
@section Scripts {
    <script src="path_to_jquery_validation"></script>
}

// because I want this page to be dark theme
@section PageStyles{
    <style>
       .theme {background-color: #000;}
    </style>

}
```

The above is a starting point. You can do more advanced implementations - e.g. `BundleConfig` (grouping/bundling/minification/versioning of css/js), and nesting of `sections`.

Hth.

Comment: That looks to be exactly what I was missing. I had assumed I could just put standard JS and CSS references in the content page, and that they would be sorted out when the body was referenced. And while they were added, they weren't fully functional. Putting the scripts in a section worked perfectly, thank you.